# Algorithm for finding relative estimate from absolute estimate

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, randomized-algorithms, error-estimation

I am trying to find a textbook reference for an algorithm that gives you a relative estimate of a quantity $a$ (i.e. $|a-\overline{a}|\leq \epsilon_{rel} a$) from an algorithm that gives you an estimate with relative error $|a-\overline{a}| \leq \epsilon_{abs}$ for $a \in (0,1]$.

The algorithm that I can think of (which I also find sometimes in some non-computer science literature) proceeds iteratively by refining the estimate $\overline{a}_i$ as follows. Run for every iteration $i$ the algorithm with error $\epsilon/2^i$, so to obtain an estimate $\overline{a}_i$. Stop iterating if this estimate satisfies the condition that $\overline{a}_1 - \frac{\epsilon}{2^i} > 0$. This is our lower bound for $a$. Once we have a lower bound, we can run the algorithm by setting $\epsilon_{abs} = \epsilon_{rel}(\overline{a}_i - \frac{\epsilon}{2^i})$.

Do you know a standard reference or a textbook for this simple idea?

Ale.